# Object passing in symfony 1.4 partial using include_partial()?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, partial

I want an object in my partial. I want to use object variables and functions in the partial.  Is it possible to pass an object in include_partial() function? Or how can I access the object in partial? I dont want to set the object in symfony request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way:

```
include_partial('moduleName/partialName', array(
  'object1' => $Object1, 
  'object2' => $Object2
));
```

then in the partial use $object1, $object2 etc.